# Can't add vxlan to bond interface

Tags: linux-networking, vxlan

I'm trying to add vxlan100 to bond0 interface but it doesn't seem to be working

Here are the commands. I have a wg0 (wireguard) interface on which I'm creating L2 vxlan100.

```
sudo ip link add vxlan100 type vxlan id 100 dev wg0 
sudo ip link add bond0 type bond
echo 0 > /sys/class/net/bond0/bonding/mode

sudo ip link set vxlan100 master bond0
```

However the last line "sudo ip link set vxlan100 master bond0" gives me an error

```
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
```

Please help, I'm not sure where I got it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reproducing this gets a specific kernel message through `dmesg`:

```
bond0: (slave vxlan100): Error -22 calling dev_set_mtu
```

(and we have EINVAL = 22 = Invalid argument)

So it's about MTU. Indeed WireGuard has MTU overhead, so is typically at MTU 1420, and [VXLAN](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/10/22/introduction-to-linux-interfaces-for-virtual-networking#vxlan) will use the parent interface's MTU minus 50 bytes (20 (IP header) + 8 (UDP header) + 8 (VXLAN specific header) + 14 (MAC header) = 50). 1420-50=1370 MTU. A few tests show that the VXLAN's MTU can't be set higher than its initial value: 1370 (but could be set lower) or would get a EINVAL.

When setting `vxlan100` as `bond0`'s slave, kernel attempts to set the slave interface's MTU to its master interface's MTU with its default of 1500 but this fails because of above: `vxlan100`'s MTU can't be increased beyond 1370.

To have the operation succeed, the master's MTU has to be lowered in advance:

```
ip link set dev bond0 mtu 1370
```

So below commands (reordered, shortened and corrected to use the IANA assigned port 4789) will work:

```
ip link add name bond0 mtu 1370 type bond mode balance-rr
ip link add name vxlan100 master bond0 type vxlan id 100 dev wg1 dstport 4789
```

Note: the information about the maximum MTU doesn't appear to be available with `ip -d link show dev vxlan100` where there is `maxmtu 65535`. I don't know if it's a bug or an other unavailable property.

To avoid having to guess the correct MTU, one can use JSON output and the [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) command to copy `vxlan100`'s MTU to `bond0`:

```
ip link add name vxlan100 type vxlan id 100 dev wg0 dstport 4789
ip link add name bond0 mtu $(ip -json link show dev vxlan100 | jq -r '.[].mtu') type bond mode balance-rr
ip link set dev vxlan100 master bond0
```

Of course similar MTU should be used in every other related places (eg: the other slaves of `bond0` and the peer link with which `bond0` communicates), or other MTU-related problems are to be expected. The other way around to keep a 1500 MTU for `bond0`: having WireGuard at MTU 1550 and thus with the outer layer with an MTU of 1630 doesn't look easy to achieve.